# Where does OKHttp stores 301 redirect entry?

Tags: android, okhttp

I'm trying to remove 301 redirect entry from one of my app. I know it supposed to be permanent, but I need a way to remove it from an app that already cached it. Where does OKHttp store the entry? Is it in a cache somewhere. I didn't set cache for the client when I build it. I couldn't find it in /data/data//cache or anywhere. Is it in a system-wide cache somewhere. Thanks

Comment: *Does* it store it? Maybe your ISP is doing that, or something upstream. Evidence please.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the cache with `Cache.urls()` and call `iterator.remove()` on whichever URLs you want to evict from the cache.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jesse. The problem is I never set a cache when i build OKHttpClient. When I tried to use client.cache().evictAll(), it gives me null pointer exception. Is there another way to access the default cache used by OKHttp?